# Changing height of vertical line in tabular

Tags: tables, rules

Is there any way of changing the height of the vertical lines of a tabular environment?

Here is my MWE:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Header 1}\\
Subheader 1 & Subheader 2 \\ \hline
Cell 1 & Cell 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

which generates:

[image]

However, I'd like to have the vertical line between Subheader 1 and Subheader 2 a bit shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `!` feature of the `array` package, together with `\vline`; however, it would be better not using vertical rules at all, as shown in the second table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % necessary for the shorter rule
\usepackage{booktabs} % for the second example
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Header 1}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c!{\vline height .8\ht\strutbox}}{Subheader 1} & Subheader 2 \\
\hline
Cell 1 & Cell 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Header 1} \\
\addlinespace
Subheader 1 & Subheader 2 \\
\midrule
Cell 1 & Cell 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{Header 1}` or:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule height 0.6ex}c!{\vrule height 0.6ex}}{Header 1}\\
Subheader 1 & Subheader 2 \\ \hline
Cell 1 & Cell 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the vertical line between Cell 1 and Cell 2 you can use

`\multicolumn{1}{|c}{Subheader 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Subheader 2} \\`.

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (as provided by `array`) but also creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the row, the columns and the cells.

Then, it's possible to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz (in the so-called `\CodeAfter`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Header 1}\\
  Subheader 1 & Subheader 2 \\ \hline
  Cell 1 & Cell 2 \\ \hline
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [shorten < = 3pt]
    \draw (1-|1) -- (last-|1) ;
    \draw (1-|last) -- (last-|last) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]